# How to capture locations when salesforce1 app goes from inactive to active state?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

"If at any point of time the App status becomes from Inactive to Active the app should capture location only when the location has changed from the previous capture." How can we determine in vf page that the salesforce app has become active?

Comment: Welcome to sfse, please take some time to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour.
Once you have done so, make sure you include details of your problem alongside with any errors you get **when applied your solution.**